# Facebook Events Cover (Graph API)

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-graph-api, cover

Facebook today released a new design for Events page (http://allfacebook.com/testing-new-layout-for-events_b111326)

There's any way to access to the cover url and also create it using Graph API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 
Facebook added 'cover' to the event field. 
You can easily test it in the Graph API explorer.
From what I have checked, it won't always return the link to the cover image location (even when the event has a cover photo.
And sometimes it won't return the regular 'picture' of the event as well (for event with cover photo and for event without cover photo.
It seems that it is still under testing.

Comment: there is a way to get the cover field by explicitly specifying it in the url **/v2.2/{event-id}?fields=cover,name,description,ticket_uri,owner,location,venue**