# Facebook API: Create Event Cover Image

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to set the new Event Cover Image over the Facebook API, but when I post the event to Facebook I only set the old small image on the left.

Is it currently possible to set the Cover Image?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is possible by using the 'cover_url' on the graph API. Here's asimilar SO question: 
[Facebook Events Cover (Graph API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034602/facebook-events-cover-graph-api)